# Why am I getting IllegalMonitorStateException for the Thread t1

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, synchronized

I'm getting this error for the code below

```
First thread about to sleep
thread 1  run
Boolean assignment done.
Woke up and about to invoke wait()
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at IncorrectSynchronization$1.run(HelloWorld.java:23)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When the Thread t1 is sleeping, I modified the lock to false from another thread.
It then throws this IllegalMonitorStateException. It's still the same object, why would modifying the value cause IllegalMonitorStateException?

When I modify the lock to false from another thread inside a synchronized block, I no longer get that error. Can anyone explain the reason for what's happening under the hood?

```
public class HelloWorld{

   public static void main( String args[] ) throws InterruptedException {
        SampleTest.runExample();
    }
}

class SampleTest{

    Boolean flag = new Boolean(true);

    public void example() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t0 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                synchronized (flag) {
                    try {
                        while (flag) {
                            System.out.println("First thread about to sleep");
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            System.out.println("Woke up and about to invoke wait()");
                            flag.wait();
                            System.out.println("wait() called");

                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                System.out.println("thread 1  run");
                flag = false;
              }
        });

        t0.start();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        t1.start();
        t0.join();
        t1.join();
    }

    public static void runExample() throws InterruptedException {
        SampleTest test = new SampleTest();
        test.example();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
flag = false;
```

This changes the *reference* of the `flag` Boolean variable, from the original `Boolean` object (which is created by the deprecated constructor which should not be used) to the pre-created `Boolean.FALSE` instance (due to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)). By the time the first thread calls `flag.wait()`, the object is no longer the same as the one it used to synchronize, hence the `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

In this scenario, it's much better to use an `AtomicBoolean` and mutate its value in the other thread:

```
AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(true);
```

Now the second thread can update the value of the same object. It should also probably notify the first thread that is waiting on the object (like `wait()`, `notify()` also requires synchronizing on the object on which it is invoked):

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
         synchronized(flag) {
             System.out.println("thread 1  run");
             flag.set(false);
             flag.notify();
         }
       }
 });
```

Comment: But doing `flag = false;` inside the synchronized block should change the reference, right?  But that doesn't throw an exception

Comment: Note that in this case `flag = false` will _not_ create a new `Boolean` instance, but the `new Boolean(true)` (which should never be used) did.